# Best Resource for Character Encodings

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, reference

I'm searching for a document (not printed) that explains in details, but still simply, the subject of character encoding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A great overview from the Programmer's perspective is:

The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)
By Joel Spolsky

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I've recently found an even better article (sorry, Joel) that is a tiny bit more technical and more correct, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried Wikipedia's [Character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset) page and it's links ?

Answer (score 2):

This perhaps?

http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode5.1.0/

Answer (score 2):

See section 2 onwards of this document http://ahds.ac.uk/creating/guides/linguistic-corpora/chapter4.htm, it has an interesting history of character encoding methods.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is actually as good a source as any to begin with:-
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding>Character-Encodings. As well as the more familiar ASCII, UTF-8 etc.  they have good information on older schemes like fieldata and the various incarnations of EBCDIC.

For in depth info on utf-8 and unicode you cannot do any better than:-
http://www.unicode.org>Unicode.org

Various manufacturs sites such as Microsoft and IBM have lots of code page info but it tends to relate to thier own hardware/software products.

Answer (score 0):

There is a French book about this called *Fontes et codages* by Yannis Haralambous, an O'Reilly book, I'm pretty sure it is or will be translated. Indeed, it is:
[Fonts and Encodings](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596102425/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

A short explanation of the basic concepts: http://www.mihai-nita.net/article.php?artID=20060806a

Answer (score 0):

[What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) is a spirituall successor to the Article on joelonsoftware.com ([linked to by lkessler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/352922/40342)).

It is just as good an introduction but is a bit better on the technical details.